# .HashMap cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview, sqlite

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String item_sub  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBController.prop_no1));
            String prop = String.valueOf(item_sub);
            String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(Search_Equipments.this, prop, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Does someone know what is wrong of this code ?

Comment: What's the purpose of this line:
String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

Comment: what exactly makes you think that `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` is a cursor? (obviously it is not)

Comment: String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)); is to get the sting value of that position

Comment: can you edit my code ?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentaion states, getItemAtPosition returns an Object, check that you cast this object to the correct Type, as it seems you don't.

> public Object getItemAtPosition (int position)
>
> Added in API level 1
> Gets the data associated with the specified position in the list.
>
> Parameters
>
> position   Which data to get
> Returns
> The data associated with the specified position in the list

Another thing is that your line:

```
String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

doesn't do anything.